# Webpage jumps to bottom when it is loaded, no clue why, what could be causing this?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am have a strange problem that I have never had before. For some reason, with this website I am designing, on this page when I load it, it jumps close to the bottom of the page, and I really have no clue why this is happening, I sure don't want it to happen (lol)

```
Here is a fiddle - it does the same thing within fiddle.
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/aileeneverlast/xgt86myL/)

Any help would be greatly appreciated, thank you so much for your time!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try removing the `autofocus` attribute from your `firstname` input field. Autofocus attribute will always scroll the page to show the focused object, I always avoid that attribute unless absolutely necessary.